# Removing a pushed file from Github Repo

Tags: github

So here's my problem. I have a stable branch (Unity). I start from here and create extending branches to add features. I wanted to NOT update the scene file in a branch, but I screwed up and it ended up in there. So I'm trying to get it out of the branch completely. I went to the branch on the website but the "delete" button is greyed out.

What I tried to do was set it up in gitignore, but that seems to have made matters worse. Now it has a red - next to the name in the website, so when I load that branch it literally deletes that file from my hard drive so I have to re-load the stable branch.

So basically I want to get rid of all references in this branch to this Game.unity file because now when I load that branch it's deleting the file, so I have to return back to the stable branch to get the file back.

Answer (score 1):

You really have a Git problem going on rather than a GitHub one.  It *sounds* like what you can do is rewrite history via an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) to clear things up.

Let's say the commit that added the bad file you don't want was 3 commits back.  You can perform this command:

`git rebase -i HEAD~3`

After doing so, Git should open a text editor and will wait for you to close it.  The editor should contain the following:

```
pick e188ac30 Add Bad FileWeDontWant
pick b03d0dd8 Add FileWeWant
pick b826995e Edit FileWeWant

# Rebase e1728338..b826995e onto e1728338 (3 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified). Use -c <commit> to reword the commit message.
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

Note that your commits are in top to bottom order (as the comments in the editor mention).  You can think of this as "replaying" the commits, with the oldest on top and newest on the bottom, since the oldest gets replayed first.

If you added the file you don't want as part of a commit that contained changes you do want, you probably want to perform an `edit`.  I think in your case this is probably what you want, since you mentioned that you also need to remove references to this file.  Thus, specify on the line of the commit that added the bad file `edit` or `e`:

```
edit e188ac30 Add Bad FileWeDontWant
pick b03d0dd8 Add FileWeWant
pick b826995e Edit FileWeWant
```

Save the changes, and close the editor.  Git will now continue with the rebase and stop at this commit where you can then make any changes (such as delete the bad file from your source, update your .gitignore to not include it, and modify any files that reference the bad file you no longer want) and then perform a `git --amend`, and keep the rest of the changes that were included in the original commit.  You will also be able to update the commit message at this time.

If you added the file in a commit that contained nothing but the addition of said file, you can `drop` the commit.  You can do this by specifying `drop` or `d` for the line of the commit that added the bad file:

```
drop e188ac30 Add Bad FileWeDontWant
pick b03d0dd8 Add FileWeWant
pick b826995e Edit FileWeWant
```

Save the changes, and close the editor.  Git will now continue with the rebase and will drop the specified commit, thus never adding the bad file.  if you do a `git log`, you'll see the commit is completely gone now.

Once done, `push` up your changes to your remote. **However, before pushing**, keep in mind that this is rewriting history, as rebases do. The documentation even mentions:

> Every commit in the range HEAD~3..HEAD with a changed message **and all of its descendants** will be rewritten. Don’t include any commit you’ve already pushed to a central server — doing so will confuse other developers by providing an alternate version of the same change.

Thus, if you are working on a big project with many hands, this could cause confusion.  If you are working solo, this shouldn't be an issue.